# How would I partition the IDLE interactive prompt using Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, console, command-line-interface

I want to create a basic multiplayer (over LAN) text-rpg. To do this, I would like to be able to have the user similtaneously see the storyline and the chat. I imagine that I could do this by splitting the console's screen. Here is an idea of what I would want:

```
<------Chat-------->
xxmbabanexx: Hello Everyone
John Smith: Sup, Playing Game.
xxmbabanexx: Help me to kill the goblin

<------Story------->
What is your name?
>>> xxmbabanexx
A goblin approaches. What do you do?
```

**Is it possible to split the console screen using Python 2.7.3?**

**NOTE:** I would like this to be cross-platform (mac, windows, linux.) If I need to use a platform-specific library, please show me the equivalents on the other OS's.

Answer (score 0):

IDLE would not be the best place to do this. You would most likely just end up running a complex curses program from within IDLE. It is possible to partition a terminal using advanced terminal libraries... *but it is extremely difficult*. I would recommend going with a gui platform such as Tkinter, pyQT, or wxPython (they all offer a fair degree of cross platform support).